# Power Function Python

Tags: python, interaction

This function is calculates the value of a^b and returns it.My question is if m=log(b) 
the best case scenario is that it does m+1 interactions 
but what is the worst case? and how many times it enters the while loop?

```
def power(a,b):
    result=1
    while b>0: # b is nonzero
        if b % 2 == 1: 
            result=result*a
        a=a*a
        b = b//2
    return result
```

Comment: This shouldn't work. `result` is undeclared and I don't understand the logic you are using to calculate the power.

Comment: Try it, it should work.It uses a mathematical principle which I interpreted into code.

Comment: When I try it I get this: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'result' referenced before assignment`.

Comment: Add result=1 before the while loop

Answer (score 3):

As @EliSadoff stated in a comment, you need an initial value of `result` in your function. Insert the line

```
result = 1
```

just after the `def` line. The code then works, and this is a standard way to implicitly use the binary representation of `b` to quickly get the exponentiation. (The loop invariant is that the value of `result * a ** b` remains constant, which shows the validity of this algorithm.)

The worst case is where your `if b % 2` line is executed every time through the `while` loop. This will happen whenever `b` is one less than a power of 2, so every digit in `b`s binary representation is one. The `while` loop condition `while b>0` is still checked only `m+1` times, but each loop now has a little more to do.

There are several ways to speed up your code. Use `while b` rather than `while b>0` and `if b & 1` rather than `if b % 2 = 1`. Use `result *= a` rather than `result = result*a` and `a *= a` rather than `a = a*a` and `b >>= 1` rather than `b = b // 2`. These are fairly minor improvements, of course. The only way to speed up the loop further is to use non-structured code, which I believe isn't possible in Python. (There is one more modification of `a` than is necessary but there is no good way to prevent that without a jump into a loop.) There are some variations on this code, such as an inner loop to keep modifying `a` and `b` as long as `b` is even, but that is not always faster.

The final code is then

```
def power(a, b):
    """Return a ** b, assuming b is a nonnegative integer"""
    result = 1
    while b:
        if b & 1: 
            result *= a
        a *= a
        b >>= 1
    return result
```

I cleaned up your code a little to better fit PEP8 (Python style standards). Note that there is no error checking in your code, especially to ensure that `b` is a nonnegative integer. I believe my code gets an infinite loop if `b` is a negative integer while yours returns a false result. So please do that error check! Also note that your code says `power(0, 0) == 1` which is pretty standard for such a function but still takes some people by surprise.